# NSCursor not changing when cursor is placed before view appears?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

So here is my problem, I have a button that should show a pointingHand cursor icon when hovered over. In your everyday case it works perfectly fine, hovering over it changes the cursor to what I expect it to. However the problem lies when I leave my cursor in an area where I expect a button to be shown.

This is where I experience the weird cursor problems, where my cursor would show the pointingHand then switch to the regular arrow followed by pointingHand and back to regular arrow which it then remains until I move the cursor out and back into the view.

Here is what I have so far within my implementation of this.

Basically I have overridden the resetCursorRects function in my nsbutton subclass,

Here are the options I have enabled for the tracking area

```
NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds, options: [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .activeInKeyWindow, .inVisibleRect], owner: self, userInfo: nil)

override func mouseEntered(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseEntered(with: theEvent)
    resetCursorRects()
}

override func resetCursorRects() {
    window?.invalidateCursorRects(for: self)
    addCursorRect(bounds, cursor: cursor.value)
}
```

So in addition to reseting the cursor rects when the button is loaded I explictly reset the rects when the cursor is within the tracking area of the button. Im not sure what Im missing here to cause the behavior that I am seeing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you call `resetCursorRects` in `mouseEntered` and `invalidateCursorRects` in `resetCursorRects`?

Comment: there is an issue with animating buttons that is not taken into account, which is why I recalculate it on `mouseEntered`

Comment: The documentation of `resetCursorRects` says "Application code should never invoke this method directly" "Use the invalidateCursorRects(for:) method instead to explicitly rebuild cursor rectangles.".

Comment: Ah yes I did come across that as well, thanks for pointing that out